# Which grant type : Implicit or Auth code (with No secret key) is suitable for Single Page Application(SPA)?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, single-page-application, restful-authentication

I went thru multiple posts saying how implicit grant is a security risk and why auth code grant with AJAX request to Authorization server should be used after redirecting to application (without client_secret passed to Auth server).

Now in 2019 there is no CORS issue as I can allow app domains on authrization server.

I have following concerns

**If I use implicit grant:**

1. Now implicit grant has security issues as Authorization server redirects to application server with token in url.
2. If I set expiration time to 5 to 10 minutes, after expiration, user will be redirected to login and its problematic especially if he is filling up important form on application. What to do in this scenario? Note that there is no refresh token in Implicit grant to update with new token, so refresh token is out of the picture.

**If I use Auth code grant:**
Suppose if I hit AJAX request after getting redirected to my main application site, and get token in exchange of code,

1. Auth code grant uses client_secret. And in javascript app where anyone can see the code, we cant use secret.
2. Assume now if I dont use client_secret. There are multiple sites that use auth server say site 1, 2, 3. Now if we say dont use secret, anyone can make host entry in nginx server that will have my site's domain name but his own IP address. In this case host injection is the issue. How to deal with it?

What approach should be taken here? I am more inclined towards auth_code for SPA but the issue is how to deal with client_secret?

Thank you for reading.

There are multiple links that recommends use Auth code grant instead of SPA. A few out of multiple links :

https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/single-page-apps/

https://medium.com/oauth-2/why-you-should-stop-using-the-oauth-implicit-grant-2436ced1c926

Answer (score 1):

You've already linked references that make it clear that you should NOT use implicit grant in an SPA.  Your confusion seems to come from your assumption that the code grant flow requires use of a client secret, but that is not the case. A SPA, like any browser or device app, is (should be) a PUBLIC client, and cannot be trusted with a secret.  Therefore, it does not use a secret.  The client secret is suitable ONLY for use with private clients, which is to say, server-side code calling the auth api.

Comment: When a client is public and when its private? See there are multiple sites that use auth server say site 1, 2, 3. Now if we say dont use secret, anyone can make host entry in nginx server that will have my site's domain name but his own IP address. In this case host injection is the issue. How to deal with it?

Comment: A client is public when it cannot protect a secret.  Any browser or device client is public, because browser code and device code can be inspected (with or without decompiling) and secrets discovered.  See the complete definition in [https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749]( RFC 6749).  A secret would not address the host entry attack you describe.  The false host could merely accept any secret.  The secret is used by the host to verify the client: it does nothing to verify the host to the client.  see also [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574846/client-authentication-on-public-client].

Answer (score 1):

the 2019 recommendations are to use a PKCE variation of the Authorization Code Flow that does not need a client secret:
https://brockallen.com/2019/01/03/the-state-of-the-implicit-flow-in-oauth2/

There's some write ups and code samples on my blog that might be useful to you - I updated this one on messages recently:
https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/